# How to draw mathematic pattern in php?

Tags: php

I want to draw a pattern like this.

```
1
2 3
3 5 8
5 8 13 21
8 13 21 34 55
```

Can somebody help me?
like in php code for this pattern is

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

is

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
            echo $j;
        }
        echo "</br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your question needs more detail.  What do you need help with, the algorithm, printing data, keeping a counter? This also smells like a homework problem so hopefully no one just gives you the solution.

Comment: Do you really need this pattern in PHP? I never heard. I used to work with such programming in QBASIC, a long time ago.

Comment: Normally this will be a good interview question not only in php, others languages too.

Comment: As i mentioned example in my question. We also draw pattern in php.

Comment: Hints: every element is a member of the [fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), so a separate [function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) to compute it would be good (memoization would speed things up too). Each line `n` starts with the `nth` element (excluding the first `1`), has `n` total elements, those being `nth+1, nth+2...`. (BTW your inner loop can use the value of the outer loop) Try it, and if you're stuck with something come back here to ask.

Comment: i have the code if you want it

Comment: @AmitKumar I have the proper code for this... You want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function nextLine($arr) {
    $n = count($arr);
    if ($n == 1) {
        $arr[$n] = 2;
    } else {
        $arr[$n] = $arr[$n-1] + $arr[$n-2];
    }
    $arr[$n+1] = $arr[$n] + $arr[$n-1];
    array_splice($arr,0,1);
    return $arr;
}
function draw() {
    $count = 5;
    $arr = array(0=>1);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        echo join(' ',$arr);
        echo '<br/>';
        $arr = nextLine($arr);
    }
}

draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$first = 0;
$second = 1;
$n =20;

print $first.'<br/>';
for($j=1;$j<=$n-1;$j++)
{
for($i=1;$i<=$j;$i++)
   {
   $final = $first + $second;
   $first = $second;
   $second = $final;
   print $final.' ';
   }
 print '<br/> ';
}
?>
```

Comment: this is incorrect.  This is just a simple incremental loop and does not meet the `fibonacci series` as described in the OP.

Comment: you are not mention fibonacci series, so ok...i updating code

Comment: It's not mentioned in the OP, it just happens to be the pattern the OP is looking for.

Comment: now you can try with your requirement....i have to given exapmle

Comment: Please try on "http://codepad.org/F6X8At2z" and test code ..

Comment: Thanx but pattern is not in right way.